# list-item icons on my nav menu display differently between Safari/Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've made a navigation menu each with it's own little icon that displays on hover but their vertical alignment differs quite abit between Safari and Firefox. Any idea how I could tackle this problem?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="about_DELETE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navbar">

<div id="logo"></div>
<div class="navbordertop"></div>
<ul>
<span class="menuico"><li><a href="#">Menu</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico2"><li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico3"><li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico4"><li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico5"><li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico6"><li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico7"><li><a href="#">Menu7</a></li></span>
<span class="menuico8"><li><a href="#">Menu8</a></li></span>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
html { 
    background: url("images/site-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 50px transparent;
    position: relative;
}
#navbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #56831b;
    background-color: #8898a2;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ebfedb;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 11px 0 8px 0;
}
#navbar ul {
    float: right;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height: 3.333em;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 95px;
    margin-top: 35px;   
}
#navbar li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 15px 15px 9px 20px;
    }
.menuico li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico2 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico3 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico4 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico5 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico6 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico7 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
.menuico8 li:hover {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 0 13px;
}
#container {
    margin: 80px auto -40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: My suggestion: define a fixed `width` and `height` for the `#navbar a` and `#navbar li` elements. Please, try and see if it works.

Comment: You can't wrap spans around `li`s like that. So your starting point has to be to get rid of those.

Comment: @J.Bruni I gave it a shot but the span's seem to move positions between the browsers..

Comment: @ralph.m Do you know a better way I can achieve this? The icons are all different shapes so I'll need to make some slightly higher/lower than others to make it looked balanced..

Comment: OK, I'm happy to help here, but I don't have enough info. I need to see things—like the images. Basically, though, you can set the images as backgrounds on the list items or `a`s themselves, which is the best way to do this.

Comment: @ralph.m Appreciate the help mate, I've tried a couple of different methods but I still have the same issue, Is there anyway I can private msg you? I don't really want to post my domain on here for seo reasons and the ip redirects elsewhere

Comment: You could place your images on a public image site (even if they are just examples), or even somewhere on your own site, and then construct a working example on jsFiddle.

Comment: OK, great. So is the issue with the positioning of the small white icons to the left of each link? Because they look exactly the same on Chrome, FF and Safari to me (Mac).

Comment: @ralph.m Hey I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rizzledon/5FScj/ I think the real problem is the padding difference on the li or ul between Safari and FF. I've tried using clearforms, changing the font(I was using a google webfont) and changing the line-heights & padding/margins to 0. The only conclusions I found for similar problems were that sometimes you just have to accept that browsers will display differently…kinda disheartening. Is there a way I can display different ul/li padding options for diff browsers without adding separate stylesheets?

Comment: Again, those are identical to me in each browser. Normally if you explicitly set margin and padding you should expect it to look the same cross browser—which is the case here for me.

Comment: @ralph.m hmm that's annoying..I took a screenshot of both browsers and placed the menu1's next to eachother http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/9346/k35v.jpg

Comment: Man, I thought you were asking about the position of the icons. Your question wasn't very clear. I've posed an answer.

Comment: @ralph.m yeh, it was a problem with the icons but it seemed like the ul or li padding was affecting the vertical positioning, I added the inline-block, used li id's instead of spanning and used the background-y to position them..both your's and J.Bruni's input was very helpful, thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block` here:

```
#navin a {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #EBFEDB;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}
```